# iPhone: Resize CALayer sublayers in view

Tags: iphone, calayer

I have set up a UIView and added a couple of CALayers as sublayers to the view's layer. Is it even possible to resize the sublayers along with the view? When I resize the layer by setting a new frame only the view's layer gets a new size, but not the sublayers. I set the setNeedsDisplayOnBoundsChange to true for the layers as well as contentsGravity to kCAGravityResizeAspect, but so far nothing has helped. Am I missing something very obvious?

Thanks and kind regards, Hans

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this?